# how to display text when hovering over game object unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My main issue is with the void OnMouseOver. Unity doesn't want to acknowledge the names "square" and "i". I can't write individual code for each game object because I have about 50 objects this code needs to apply to. I need to have a specific number pop up when I hover over a square. I'm not sure if the void OnMouseOver should be in the void Start or not, but when it was outside of it there were even more errors. Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class HeaterRead : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\labom\Documents\Work 
    Files\Heater_Main_Output.csv"))
        {
            List<float> listTi = new List<float>();
            List<float> listVe = new List<float>();
            List<float> listTe = new List<float>();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                listTi.Add(float.Parse(values[0]));
                listVe.Add(float.Parse(values[2]));
                listTe.Add(float.Parse(values[3]));
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }

           // temperature minimum = 300F;
           // temperature maximum = 720F;

            Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, (listTe[0] / 420F) - 0.71F);


            List<GameObject> listS = new List<GameObject>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
            {
                GameObject square = GameObject.Find("Square" + i.ToString());
                square.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, (listTe[i - 1] / 420F) - 0.71F), 0, 0, 1);
                Debug.Log(square.name + "   " + listTi[i-1].ToString() + "(s)   " + listVe[i-1].ToString() + "(10 m/s)   " + listTe[i-1].ToString() + "(F)   " + (Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, (listTe[0] / 420F) - 0.71F)) + "% R");
            }

            void OnMouseOver()
            {
            Debug.Log(square.name + "   " + listTi[i-1].ToString() + "(s)   " + listVe[i-1].ToString() + "(10 m/s)   " + listTe[i-1].ToString() + "(F)   " + (Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, (listTe[0] / 420F) - 0.71F)) + "% R");
            }

        }
    }

    public string stringToEdit = "Heater Dashboard";
    public string stringToEdit2 = "Expected Readings";
    public string stringToEdit3 = "Actual Readings";


    void OnGUI()
    {
        stringToEdit = GUI.TextField(new Rect(300, 10, 115, 20), stringToEdit, 25);
    stringToEdit2 = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 125, 120, 20), stringToEdit2, 25);
    stringToEdit3 = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 270, 105, 20), stringToEdit3, 25);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now! Also just because you are using a certain IDE doesn't mean your question is about that IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you created a **local function** *OnMouseOver()*, which is only available inside a *Start()* method.

Secondly... you created a **local** `square` **variable** inside a loop, thus it cannot be available beyond loop, the same thing with `i`, ***but you trying to call them both outside that for-loop***.

Comment: so then all I would need to do is remove the OnMouseOver() from the Start(), and define the variables globally?

Comment: Actually, idk what you code does, and what precisely you want to do, but if you want just avoid errors, this can help